# How to get macros to work when sheet name is changed

Tags: excel, vba

How do I make it so my macro will work on a spreadsheet even if someone changes the name of the tab for Sheet1, Sheet2, etc.

For example this snippet from my code:

```
Set MyWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(DataDialog.SelectedItems(Counter))
Set MySheet = MyWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

Gets the Run-time error '9':

> Subscript out of range

The issue is I need this macro to able to be used on multiple different workbooks with different named tabs and in a lot of cases tabs will be hidden and what appears to be Sheet1 is really Sheet3.
Is there a way to have a macro work on the active sheet alone?

Comment: Use the sheet codeName (the name which appears in the VB editor).  Eg: `Sheet1.Range("A1")` will always work even if the user renames the sheet or changes its position.  You can change the code name to make it more descriptive.

Comment: @TimWilliams; respectfully: the accepted answer, without this comment, is even more dangerous than no answer at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, You dont have to hardcode "Sheet1". Instead you can do like following:

Method 1:
Declare variable

```
Dim sName as string
sName = Activesheet.Name
```

And then you can use name in the variable sName instead of hardcoding it.

Method 2:
You can use index of sheets

```
sName = Sheets(1).Name
```

Where 1 indicates index number of sheets in workbook.

So, You can use any of the above two methods to get name of sheet when sheet name changes.

Comment: Glad to help you!!! You can Upvote this answer and check the answer if you like the solution...

Comment: ActiveSheet will only work if it is the activesheet - it's very possible, and happens often, that you want the VBA to work on a sheet that isn't the active one.  `Sheets(1)` suffers a similar problem to renaming the sheet - if the user accidentally drags the sheet to another position it's no longer `Sheets(1)`.  @Tim Williams comment on your original post is the most reliable way.  As you said: "in a lot of cases tabs will be hidden" - you'll run into problems there.

Comment: My own code initially referenced a sheet by name. After having renamed it (of course also in the macro), the macro no longer worked. I tried both methods in this answer, but to no avail: the macro is still not working. After renaming the sheet to its original name, the macro works again (using any of the three methods). Somehow the VBA macro cannot reach a renamed sheet.